# problems with Python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Environment: Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64), OSX 10.13, tclsh 8.6
I can't display the menus widget. I tried to write a code using menu of Tkinter, but nothing is showing on the screen. Anyone can help me, please. My code:

```
from tkinter import *


def NewFile():
    print("New File!")
def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename()
    print(name)
def About():
    print ("This is a simple example of a menu")

root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=NewFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=OpenFile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

helpmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=About)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code runs perfectly fine on my computer (well, after I imported `tkinter.filedialog`). Do you get any error?

Comment: On OSX, tkinter menus appear like any other OSX app on the menubar at the top of the screen rather than the top of the window. Is the menu visible at the top of the screen?

Comment: I also don't have any problems running this (Windows 10, Python 3.6.2 IDLE). Have you tried running this outside of Anaconda, perhaps in another IDE?